# firebase database for chat application like whatsapp with ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, ionic4

i would like to create chat application like whatsapp,

i tried many samples but still now i didn't get full picture how to implement this, because how we can design the database everyone is giving sample json structure but how we can use that json in ionic application ?? or we have to use functions ??

can any one help me the full database and how we can use that in ionic app ?

https://web.chat21.org/

i am planing to implement chat application like this

here is the one to one chat simple code, but i want recent chats list, users list etc.

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public name = 'surendra';
  messagesList = [];
  ref = firebase.database().ref('chatrooms/');
  newmessage: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
  ) {
    this.ref.on('value', data => {
      let tmp = [];
      data.forEach(data => {
        tmp.push({
          key: data.key,
          name: data.val().name,
          message: data.val().message
        })
      });
      this.messagesList = tmp;
    });
  }

  send() {
    this.ref.push({
      name: this.name,
      message: this.newmessage
    });
  }
}
```